# #Value! error in valid formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Im using the following formula and have tried several ways to eliminate the #VALUE! error without any success.

Here is the formula:

```
=IF(SEARCH("Agent Name & ID:",A14)>0,(A15)*60*24,"")
```

if the search is valid I get the correct result, however if it's not valid I get the `#VALUE!` error rather than the blank cell indicated by the "".

Please help I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your SEARCH formula is returning the #Value! error before it gets to the IF formula. Try wrapping your SEARCH with an IFERROR to handle that before it's evaluated by the IF formula.

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("Agent Name & ID",A14),"")<>"",(A15)*60*24,"")
```

This will evaluate SEARCH and if it finds the String, returns the value from A14, otherwise it returns a blank.  Then, the IF statement returns blank for blank, or your calculated value from A15.

You could also do this with a single IFERROR formula, as suggested by Milena Petrovic, but you need to add an extra calculation.  This should also work:

```
=IFERROR((SEARCH("Agent ID & Name",A14)*0)+((A15)*60*24),"")
```

If it finds the search text, it will return a value which converts to a 0 by multiplication.  This 0 can then be safely added to your calculated field.  It if doesn't find the value, then the error is converted to a simple blank as before.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said,the problem is with the SEARCH function. Ir returns #VALUE when it doesn't find the specified string ("Agent Name & ID:") in this example

Try to use the IfError function instead of IF

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/iferror-function-HA001231765.aspx

Comment: I get the same error with the iferror, not sure why the search is causing this

Comment: The issue is that IFERROR has only 2 parameters, so you cannot just replace IF in the statement. What do you get for =IFERROR(SEARCH("Agent Name & ID:",A14), "")